# Disable escape characters in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to disable escape characters in a MySQL query? For example, for the following table:

```
mysql> select * from test1;
+------------------------+-------+
| name                   | value |
+------------------------+-------+
| C:\\media\data\temp\   |     1 |
| C:\\media\data\temp    |     2 |
| /unix/media/data/temp  |     3 |
| /unix/media/data/temp/ |     4 |
+------------------------+-------+
```

I want the following to be a valid query:

```
mysql> select * from test1 where name='C:\\media\data\temp\';
```

I know that I can instead use

```
mysql> select * from test1 where name='C:\\\\media\\data\\temp\\';
```

But I am building this query using my_snprintf(), so there instead I have to use

```
C:\\\\\\\\media\\\\data\\\\temp\\\\
```

...and so on!
Is there a way to disable escape characters for a single MySQL query ?

Comment: What language are you doing this in? I couldn't find any info for my_snprintf on the internet. Is there no way you can create a function that escapes for you?

Comment: I am using C. my_snprintf() - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/plugin-services.html . It does mostly what sprintf does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can disable backslash escapes by setting [NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) in the SQL mode:

```
-- save mode & disable backslashes
SET @old_sql_mode=@@sql_mode;
SET @@sql_mode=CONCAT_WS(',', @@sql_mode, 'NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES');

-- run the query
SELECT 'C:\\media\data\temp\';

-- enable backslashes
SET @@sql_mode=@old_sql_mode;
```

Answer (score 5):

For tabular output in MySQL command line, the “boxing” around columns enables one column value to be distinguished from another. For non-tabular output (such as is produced in batch mode or when the `--batch` or `--silent` option is given), special characters are escaped in the output so they can be identified easily. Newline, tab, NUL, and backslash are written as \n, \t, \0, and \. The `--raw` option disables this character escaping.